# Laravel Trait not found on remote server, was ok locally

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \Kalnoy\Nestedset\Nodetrait;

class Category extends Model
{
    use NodeTrait;
}
```

It is working correctly on my homestead local environment, after trying to publish it on a vps (and run the composer install and update) i got the error of this trait not being found

> FatalErrorException in Category.php line 10: Trait
>   'Kalnoy\Nestedset\Nodetrait' not found

why can it be?

Comment: Try like this use App\Kalnoy\Nestedset\Nodetrait;

Comment: @Komal it didn't help. Same error

Comment: Are you added any provider classes for this?

Comment: @Komal no i didn't

Comment: Have you double checked the names? I mean capital letters differences for example?

Comment: @UmbertP. it's a cloned repository which is working fine locally... I'm thinking more on some problem with my apache configuration

Comment: Nodetrait vs NodeTrait - please double check upper-lower case in class name, file name, namespace name

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then test.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comments the problem was upper-lower case syntax error in the namespace... I still can't explain how it was working fine locally but good it's working now.

Comment: Set the question as resolved please. 

Always take in consideration that different systems have case sensitive differences, linux is case sensitive, mac is not for example.